# Insert line in Monaco editor preserving selection

Tags: monaco-editor

I'd like to insert a line of text before the existing text at a given line number. I'm currently using this:

```js
const insertionRange = new monaco.Range(
    lineNo, this.getModel().getLineMinColumn(lineNo),
    lineNo, this.getModel().getLineMinColumn(lineNo),
);
this.executeEdits("", [{ range: insertionRange, text: insertMe + "\n" }]);
```

However I think I also need to push the insertion cursor(s) and any selections that follow the text that I inserted. So if before I had:

```
1  So we beat on,
2  borne back ceaselessly into the past.|
```

after inserting a line before line 2, I want the insertion point to be at the end of line 3:

```
1  So we beat on,
2  boats against the current,
3  borne back ceaselessly into the past.|
```

`ICodeEditor.executeEdits` does take an optional third `ICursorStateComputer` option which can be used to modify the cursor after an edit takes place, but I'm not sure how to use it.

There is also an [`InsertLineBeforeAction`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a512c86f10e7d808b25e3ab5844e8c2783e1e8d8/src/vs/editor/contrib/linesOperations/linesOperations.ts#L484) which I might be able to use instead of doing this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to compute new selections, maybe something like this:

```
const newSelections = this.getSelections().map((s) => {
    if (s.endLineNumber >= lineNo) s.endLineNumber ++;
    if (s.positionLineNumber >= lineNo) s.positionLineNumber ++;
    if (s.selectionStartLineNumber >= lineNo) s.selectionStartLineNumber ++;
    if (s.startLineNumber >= inputLineNum) s.startLineNumber ++;
    return s;
});
```

then pass `newSelections` as the third argument to `executeEdits`.